# Is this a correct proof of the convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{2n^2+n+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was asked to show whether the following series converges or diverges.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{2n^2+n+1}$$

After attempting a direct proof by limit comparison, I noticed a simpler approach and I wonder if it is valid.

$\alpha$) Let $a_n= \dfrac{\sqrt{n+2}}{2n^2+n+1}, b_n=\dfrac{\sqrt{n+2}}{2n^2}$, such that $a_n < b_n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$\beta)$ Let $c_n = \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2n^2}=\dfrac{1}{2n^\frac{3}{2}}$. Then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{b_n}{c_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \Big(\frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{2n^2}\times 2n^{\frac{3}{2}} \Big) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{n+2}{n}}=1$$

Since $\sum c_n$ is of the form $\sum \dfrac{1}{n^p}$ with $p>1$, it converges, and thus we have shown via limit comparison that $b_n$ converges.

$\gamma)$ Since ($\beta$) $b_n$ converges and ($\alpha$) $a_n < b_n$, we prove by direct comparison that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{2n^2+n+1}$ converges.

I am pretty new to comparison tests and I want to make sure my approach is correct. Thank you!

Comment: Your approach is correct. Here's another way you could have thought about this:
$$\frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{2n^2+n+1} \leq \frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{2n^2+n} \leq \frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{n^2+2n} \leq \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+2}} \leq \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

Now, the result follows by direct comparison.

Comment: That is a nicer, more direct approach. I like it! Thanks for pointing it out.